# Gradle IllegalAccessError: Tried to access class gradle.BasePlugin$_addDependency_closure134

Tags: gradle, android-studio

So, after having a mac os x update and a Android Studio Update something has broken.
I have searched the better part of the morning to find any clue as to what has happend but found nothing.

The error I get is:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':BSS'.
>
> > A problem occurred configuring project ':BSS:libs:SlidingMenuLib'.
> >     java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class 
> >     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_addDependency_closure134 from class 
> >     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin

I have not changed anything in the projectstructure, from last week, when it did work, this just suddenly happened over the weekend.

The build.gradle for the SlidingMenuLib is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

}
```

What is going on?

Comment: I'd try deleting your ~/.gradle directory and rebuilding.

Comment: It does not solve the issue, and more to it, i can still compile the code I am developing, it's just gradle / intellij who behaves weird all of a sudden.